# Stackoverflow plan-b

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

Stackoverflow have come to the point (and way beyond) where all geeks and programmers out there would suffer a great deal if it went black tomorrow.

I don't doubt that Stackoverflow have a good backup regime, but a lot of things could happen.

It be great if Stackoverflow had some sort of db-dump feature to mitigate this. It doesn't haveto be a full dump. But a dump with the questions and accepted answers would be almost just as good. It would also be a great offline-search tool for places without internet..

Is this up for consideration?

Comment: "I doubt that Stackoverflow have a good backup regime" - the context of your sentence indicates that you meant "don't doubt"?

Comment: I did search for "database dump" on meta, but it didnt turn up much related info. Sorry for not searching on similar terms..

Comment: There has been a periodic [tag:data-dump] for a while now (see the [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/) and other questions in that tag).

Comment: @TimPost thanks for the correction.. Edited the question.

Comment: There's always Experts Exchange.

Comment: @JayRiggs I can see Jeff Atwood conjuring up a lightning bolt just for you ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can already download a regular data dump from http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump.

Explore the datadumps using an online query tool at https://data.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow (and the rest of our sites) actually exist in two data centers at once, one in NY and one in Oregon. In fact, in the event of looming or eminent catastrophe, our devs and system administrators can throw a series of things to (rather quickly) fail over from one DC to another. We also have a rather paranoid backup strategy, all from [hard learned lessons](http://thisdeveloperslife.com/post/2-0-2-pressure).

The dumps aren't as useful for backup purposes because they don't contain a lot of data that we need to actually offer the site (with accounts, histories, etc) - but they are available for those interested in [doing interesting things with the data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facebook-recruiting-iii-keyword-extraction), or remixing & reusing the content [with proper attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

While we can't account for giant meteors, raptors (well, they may have a plan for raptors, I'm not certain but I do know the data centers are *rudely* secure) and other world ending scenarios, we're pretty confident that we're not going to go black :)

Comment: Regarding raptors I'm more than sure that Jeff is holding bunch of unicorns somewhere, ready to disintegrate any evil raptor on sight.

Comment: And of course: Google indexes so insanely fast that its cache might be plan B if all above fails. (Ok, Google doesn't expose the cache for very new questions, but most is available.)

Comment: I have pictures of our rather heavily armed system administrators, will include them in this shortly to account for raptors (if you happen to have that picture of Pete with several automatic weapons strapped to him, feel free to just edit it in)